# Get InputBase value out from the same component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have different places that use the same input component.
Below are the input component:

```
const stationSelection = (stationName) => {
   return (
      <Paper
         component="form"
         elevation={5}
         sx={{
            m: '10px 0 30px 5px',
            p: '2px 4px',
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            width: 300,
         }}
      >

      //HERE
      <InputBase
         sx={{ ml: 1, flex: 1 }}
         placeholder="Please select a station."
         value={stationName}
         onChange={ /*how to get the data each of the input*/ }
      />


      <Divider sx={{ height: 28, m: 0.5 }} orientation="vertical" />
      <IconButton
         color="primary"
         sx={{ p: '10px' }}
         aria-label="directions"
      >
         <ArrowDropDownCircleOutlinedIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </Paper>
   )
}
```

In my react app, I will use it two times for different input.

```
<CardContent className="default-font">
   <Box sx={{ mb: 10 }}>
      <Box className="bold">DEPARTURE STATION</Box>
      {stationSelection(departStation)}             //HERE

      <Box className="center">
         <Box className="bold" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            ARRIVAL STATION
         </Box>
         <IconButton
            color="primary"
            sx={{ p: '5px', m: '-10px 0 -10px 0' }}
         >
            <ImportExportIcon />
         </IconButton>
      </Box>
   {stationSelection(arriveStation)}                //HERE
   </Box>

   {ticketDetails()}
</CardContent>
```

Because I use it two times by using the different variables into the same component, it makes it difficult for me to found out a way to get the data out from the component.
Here are my useState in case you need that.

```
const [departStation, setDepartStation] = useState('');
const [arriveStation, setArriveStation] = useState('');
```

Basically, I need to get that two user input.
[Full code link.](https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-microservice-qp1dy?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: your question is not clear, where else do you want to use this input, and what is the issue? can you provide a link to your code?

Comment: Hey @GuyPerry, I added the link above, sorry for the confusion of my explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you functional component should start with a capital letter, so change your declaration to:

```
const StationSelection = ...
```

Second, in order to edit the state in your component, you should also pass the setter method, and change it in the `onChange` function:

```
const StationSelection = ({ stationName, setStationName }) => {
    const handleStationChange = (e) => {
        setStationName(e.target.value)
    }

   return (
      <Paper
         component="form"
         elevation={5}
         sx={{
            m: '10px 0 30px 5px',
            p: '2px 4px',
            display: 'flex',
            alignItems: 'center',
            width: 300,
         }}
      >

      //HERE
      <InputBase
         sx={{ ml: 1, flex: 1 }}
         placeholder="Please select a station."
         value={stationName}
         onChange={handleStationChange}
      />


      <Divider sx={{ height: 28, m: 0.5 }} orientation="vertical" />
      <IconButton
         color="primary"
         sx={{ p: '10px' }}
         aria-label="directions"
      >
         <ArrowDropDownCircleOutlinedIcon />
      </IconButton>
    </Paper>
   )
}
```

Finally, change your main component like this

```
<CardContent className="default-font">
   <Box sx={{ mb: 10 }}>
      <Box className="bold">DEPARTURE STATION</Box>
      <StationSelection stationName={departStation} setStationName={setDepartStation} />

      <Box className="center">
         <Box className="bold" sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
            ARRIVAL STATION
         </Box>
         <IconButton
            color="primary"
            sx={{ p: '5px', m: '-10px 0 -10px 0' }}
         >
            <ImportExportIcon />
         </IconButton>
      </Box>
   
        <StationSelection stationName={arriveStation} setStationName={setArriveStation} />
   </Box>

   {ticketDetails()}
</CardContent>
```